# Protocol declaration not being found

Tags: objective-c, delegates, protocols

So I have one class `CommentViewController.h` in which I have

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@protocol CommentViewControllerDelegate;

@interface CommentViewController : UIViewController {
id <CommentViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
}

 @property (nonatomic, assign) id <CommentViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

- (IBAction)submit:(id)sender;

-(IBAction)cancel:(id)sender;

 @end

@protocol CommentViewControllerDelegate
-(void)commentViewControllerDidFinish:(CommentViewController *)controller;
@end
```

I synthesized delegate in the implementation

I try to access the protocol in `FirstViewController.h`:

```
 #import "CommentViewController.h"
 @interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <CommentViewControllerDelegate>
```

And in the implantation of `FirstViewController` :

```
 - (void)commentViewControllerDidFinish:(CommentViewController *)controller {
 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }
```

The error appears on this line:

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <CommentViewControllerDelegate>
```

Error: `Cannot find protocol declaration for 'CommentViewControllerDelegate'; did you mean 'UISplitViewControllerDelegate'?`

Am I missing something? I always have trouble with protocols and delegates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a loop in your include files.

Remove this line from `CommentViewController.h`:

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
```

It's not referenced in that header file, and if it were, you could simply put:

```
@class FirstViewController;
```

instead of including the whole file.

Comment: I love how you answered this in '12 and for some weird reason it was exactly the solution I was looking for five years later! <3